# Zoom In after Rotation C# Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, rotation, zooming

I have created a project that rotates the model (camera view) on Z-axis, 360 degrees (moves 10 degrees 36 times to compleete the 360 degrees) and when the model comes back to its initial position the rotation stops.

After the rotation stops I want to Zoom-In and then start rotating again having the Zoomed coordinates.

As you can see I have added a for loop that stops the model after 36 times of rotating 10 degrees and then I used

```
 DrawingControl.ZoomTo(r3D);
```

To Zoom-in.

**The problem** is that it does stop and zoom but for milliseconds and then it shows the initial coordinates. I added **else** at the end of **if** statement but after zooming everything disappears. No model, no nothing.

**QUESTION**
How can I Zoom-In and then continue rotating with the new coordinates after the rotation?

*This is the initial and end position/view*

[image]

*This is the result if I add else after if statement*

[image]

*This is the code that I used*

```
private void RotatingModelAround(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Counter++;

       if (Counter == 37)
       {    //will stop after it rotates 36 times// will stop to its initial position
             var r3D = new XbimRect3D(2,-1,0,0,0,0);
           dispatcherTimer.Stop();
            _camChanged = false;
           DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed += Camera_Changed;
           //Zoom
           DrawingControl.ZoomTo(r3D);
           DrawingControl.Viewport.Camera.Changed -= Camera_Changed;
           if (!_camChanged)
               DrawingControl.ClipBaseSelected(0.15);

       }
           Vector3D vAxis = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M31, gCamWC.M32, gCamWC.M33);  //Rotate about world z-axis.
                AxisAngleRotation3D myRotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(vAxis, 10);
                RotateTransform3D myRotationTransform = new RotateTransform3D(myRotation);

                Matrix3D doTranslation = new Matrix3D();
                doTranslation.M24 = 3;  // Offset along camera y-axis.         Presumed to be parallel to world plane.

                gCamWC.Append(myRotationTransform.Value);
                gCamWC.Append(doTranslation);

                Point3D camPosition = new Point3D(gCamWC.M14, gCamWC.M24, gCamWC.M34);
                Vector3D camLookAt = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M11, gCamWC.M21, gCamWC.M31);
                Vector3D camLookUp = new Vector3D(gCamWC.M13, gCamWC.M23, gCamWC.M33);

                DrawingControl.Viewport.SetView(camPosition, camLookAt, camLookUp, 0);

   }
```